# Spring Controller request parameter as POJO coming from jQuery get()

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

Updated:

There might be some who are looking for a way to pass a JSON object as ajax parameter then convert into a POJO in a spring controller.
Others might get a 400 Bad Request error if they use Request Method GET. Please use the type POST in both ajax and in spring controller.

### JQuery code

```
var PaxTypeFare = function(paxType, baseFare, totalFeesAndTaxes, totalAmount) {   
    this.paxType = paxType;   
    this.baseFare = baseFare;   
    this.totalFeesAndTaxes = totalFeesAndTaxes;   
    this.totalAmount = totalAmount;   
}   

var SpaceShipTripInfo = function(from, to, fromSchedule, toSchedule){   
    this.from = from;   
    this.to = to;   
    this.fromSchedule = fromSchedule;   
    this.toSchedule = toSchedule;   
};   

...   

var tInfos = new Array();   
tInfos.push(new SpaceShipTripInfo("EARTH", "MOON", "2015-12-21T04:30:00", "2015-12-21T06:50:00"));   
tInfos.push(new SpaceShipTripInfo("MOON", "MARS", "2015-12-21T03:30:00", "2015-12-21T011:10:00"));   
tInfos.push(new SpaceShipTripInfo("VENUS", "KEPLER", "2015-12-21T01:30:00", "2015-12-21T22:30:00"));   
tInfos.push(new SpaceShipTripInfo("EARTH", "SUN", "2015-12-20T02:30:00", "2015-12-29T15:10:00"));   

var adultFares = new PaxTypeFare("ADT", 1000, 300, 1300);   
var childFares = new PaxTypeFare("CHD", 750, 250, 1000);   
var infantFares = null;   

var data = {   
    tripInfos: tInfos,   
    adultFares: adultFares,   
    childFares: childFares,   
    infantFares: infantFares,   
    adultCount: 1,   
    childCount: 1,   
    infantCount: 0   
};   

var url = "/getSelectedTripPrices";   
$.ajax({   
    url: url,   
    data: JSON.stringify(data),   
    contentType: "application/json",   
    type: "POST",  
    success: function (strHtml) {   
        //...   
    } 
});
```

### JSON data

```
{   
    "tripInfos":[   
        {   
            "from":"EARTH",   
            "to":"MOON",   
            "fromSchedule":"2015-12-21T04:30:00",   
            "toSchedule":"2015-12-21T06:50:00"   
        },   
        {   
            "from":"MOON",   
            "to":"MARS",   
            "fromSchedule":"2015-12-21T03:30:00",   
            "toSchedule":"2015-12-21T011:10:00"   
        },   
        {   
            "from":"VENUS",   
            "to":"KEPLER",   
            "fromSchedule":"2015-12-21T01:30:00",   
            "toSchedule":"2015-12-21T22:30:00"   
        },   
        {   
            "from":"EARTH",   
            "to":"SUN",   
            "fromSchedule":"2015-12-20T02:30:00",   
            "toSchedule":"2015-12-29T15:10:00"   
        }   
    ],   
    "adultFares":{   
        "paxType":"ADT",   
        "baseFare":"1000",   
        "totalFeesAndTaxes":"300",   
        "totalAmount":"1300.00"   
    },   
    "childFares":{   
        "paxType":"CHD",   
        "baseFare":"750",   
        "totalFeesAndTaxes":"250",   
        "totalAmount":"1000.00"   
    },   
    "infantFares": null,   
    "adultCount":"1",   
    "childCount":"1",   
    "infantCount":"0"     
}
```

### ItineraryPrice Class

```
public Class ItineraryPrice {   
    private List<ItineraryPrice.SpaceShipTripInfo> tripInfos;  
    private ItineraryPrice.PaxTypeFare adultFares;  
    private ItineraryPrice.PaxTypeFare childFares;  
    private ItineraryPrice.PaxTypeFare infantFares;  

    private int adultCount;  
    private int childCount;  
    private int infantCount;  

    //Getters and Setters here  

    public static class SpaceShipTripInfo {  
        private String from;  
        private String to;  
        private String fromSchedule;  
        private String toSchedule  
        //Getters and Setters here  
    }  

    public static class PaxTypeFare {  
        private String paxType;  
        private Double baseFare;  
        private Double totalFeesAndTaxes;  
        private Double totalAmount;  
        //Getters and Setters here  
    }  
}
```

### Spring Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getSelectedTripPrices", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")   
@ResponseBody   
public ModelAndView getSelectedTripPrices(HttpSession session,   
 @RequestBody ItineraryPrice itineraryPrice,   
 BindingResult bindingResult) {   

    if(null != itineraryPrice.getAdultFares()){  
        System.out.println("[Type-code]: "              + itineraryPrice.getAdultFares().getPaxType());  
        System.out.println("[Type-baseFare]: "          + itineraryPrice.getAdultFares().getBaseFare());  
        System.out.println("[Type-totalFeesAndTaxes]: " + itineraryPrice.getAdultFares().getTotalFeesAndTaxes());  
        System.out.println("[Type-totalAmount]: "       + itineraryPrice.getAdultFares().getTotalAmount());  
    }  
    else  
        System.out.println("ADULT-FARES-NULL");  

    if(null != itineraryPrice.getChildFares()){  
        System.out.println("[Type-code]: "              + itineraryPrice.getChildFares().getPaxType());  
        System.out.println("[Type-baseFare]: "          + itineraryPrice.getChildFares().getBaseFare());  
        System.out.println("[Type-totalFeesAndTaxes]: " + itineraryPrice.getChildFares().getTotalFeesAndTaxes());  
        System.out.println("[Type-totalAmount]: "       + itineraryPrice.getChildFares().getTotalAmount());  
    }  
    else  
        System.out.println("CHILD-FARES-NULL");  

    if(null != itineraryPrice.getInfantFares()){  
        System.out.println("[Type-code]: "              + itineraryPrice.getInfantFares().getPaxType());  
        System.out.println("[Type-baseFare]: "          + itineraryPrice.getInfantFares().getBaseFare());  
        System.out.println("[Type-totalFeesAndTaxes]: " + itineraryPrice.getInfantFares().getTotalFeesAndTaxes());  
        System.out.println("[Type-totalAmount]: "       + itineraryPrice.getInfantFares().getTotalAmount());  
    }  
    else  
        System.out.println("INFANT-FARES-NULL");  
}
```

Comment: Updated the posted codes to adjust ajax data and format. Also used RequestBody instead of ModelAttribute and used method type POST instead of GET. but I am still getting a 400 Bad Request Error. What changes do I need to make with these codes in order to pass ajax JSON data into spring as POJO? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to transform these data to JSON objects: 
to send info to the RequestParam you can use this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: './controller/find.htm',
            data: {
                adultCount: 1,
                childCount: 2,
                childCount: 3
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('response=', data);
            }
        });
```

the ModelAttribute is use to macth form variables, you need to use RequestBody and you need to create a Json object in jquery and add that in the data section in the code.

Comment: I converted the parameters into data objects and applied JSON.stringify()... but I am getting error 400 bad request.

Comment: Below is the link of the ajax request...
http://localhost:8080/getSelectedTripPrices?{%22tripInfos%22:[{%22from%22:%22EARTH%22,%22to%22:%22MOON%22,%22fromSchedule%22:%222015-12-21T04:30:00%22,%22toSchedule%22:%222015-12-21T06:50:00%22}],%22adultFares%22:{%22paxType%22:%22ADT%22,%22baseFare%22:%221000%22,%22totalFeesAndTaxes%22:%22300%22,%22totalAmount%22:%221300.00%22},%22childFares%22: null,%22infantFares%22: null,%22adultCount%22:%221%22,%22childCount%22:%221%22,%22infantCount%22:%220%22}

Comment: After chanding ModelAttribute into RequestBody ... I am not getting a HTTP 415 Error - having the same request link posted in the above comment.

Comment: Do not send the object in the url... use the code that I give you and change the requestmethod to post

Comment: I have updated the codes above. I am still getting a 400 Bad Request error.

Comment: Your url need the name of Your project.

Comment: Hi Jhon, i forgot to include <c:url> tag above... I am thinking if I needed Jackson for my problem since I have not used jackson here. thanks